# React question : how to pass an id from a component to another on click?

Tags: reactjs

I need your help with an app that I am building. It has a forum page and I have some issues with the forum and post components.
I am trying to pass the id of the post that the user clicked on, with `history.push` so on the post page the `id` in the url that I try to get with `useParams`, has the value of the one I send with `history.push`. The purpose is for some queries I do so I show the post with its comments.
For now the layout isn’t great because I have to make this feature work.
I do not understand why it doesn’t. My console.logs show null or undefined which make no sense to me.
Thank you if you can help me with this.

Here you have two routes present in the App component. It is important for the last route, the Post one were I use `:id` so I can get it with `useParams`.

```
{/* Route for Trainings Wakeup Rebirth */}
<Route path='#forum' exact component={TrainingsWakeupRebirth} />
<Route path='#forum/:id' exact component={Post} />
```

Here you have the entire code of the Forum page. Like that you can see how I use `history.push` to send the `value.id` of the post to the `Post` component and the way the component itself is built.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";
import Post from "../Post/Post";
import './TrainingsWakeupRebirth.scss';
import axios from "axios";

const TrainingsWakeupRebirth = (props) => {
    
    let history = useHistory();

    // const forumSectionRef = useRef();
    // const postSectionRef = useRef();
    

    const forumSection = document.getElementById('forum-block-wrapper');
    const postSection = document.getElementById('post-section');

    const showPost = () => {
        if (forumSection.style.display === 'block') {
            return forumSection.style.display = 'none',
            postSection.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            return forumSection.style.display = 'block',
            postSection.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    const [listOfPosts, setListsOfPosts] = useState([]);
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);

    const postsPerPage = 2;
    const pagesVisited = pageNumber * postsPerPage;


    const displayPosts = listOfPosts.slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + postsPerPage).map((value, key) => {
        const forParams = () => {
            return history.push(`#forum/${value.id}`);
        }
        const executeAll = () => {
            forParams();
            showPost();
            if(forParams()) {
                let id = value.id;
                return id;
            }
        }

        return (
            <div key={key}>
                <div className="topic-row" onClick={() => {executeAll()}}>
                    <div className="topic-title">{value.title}</div>
                    <div className="topic-image">
                        <img src={value.image} alt=""></img>
                    </div>
                    <div className="topic-message">{value.postText}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });

    const pageCount = Math.ceil(listOfPosts.length / postsPerPage);

    const changePage = ({selected}) => {
        setPageNumber(selected); 
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/posts").then((response) => {
            setListsOfPosts(response.data);
        });
    }, []);

    console.log(listOfPosts);

    return (
        <div className="forum" id="forum">
            <div className="forum-section-wrapper page" id="forum-wrapper">
                <div className="fluid-grid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <div className="title">
                                <h1><span className="first-title-part">Krishna</span><span className="second-title-part">Hara</span></h1>
                            </div>
                            <div className="quote">
                                <span className="quote-left">FORUM</span><span className="quote-right">Eco Village</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <div className="forum-block-wrapper" id="forum-block-wrapper">
                                {displayPosts}
                                <ReactPaginate 
                                    previousLabel={"Previous"}
                                    nextLabel={"Next"}
                                    pageCount={pageCount}
                                    onPageChange={changePage}
                                    containerClassName={"paginationBttns"}
                                    previousLinkClassName={"previousBttn"}
                                    nextLinkClassName={"nextBttn"}
                                    activeClassName={"paginationActive"}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="post-section" id="post-section">
                <div className="fluid-grid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <Post />
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}; 

export default TrainingsWakeupRebirth;
```

Here is some code from the `Post` component, so you can see the code that should work but doesn't. Also the `console.log(id)`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const Post = (props) => {

    let { id } = useParams();
    const [postObject, setPostObject] = useState({});
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
    const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState("");
    console.log(id);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/posts/byId/${id}`).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            setPostObject(response.data);
        });

        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/comments/${id}`).then((response) => {
            setComments(response.data);
        });
    }, [id]);

    const addComment = () => {
        axios.post("http://localhost:3001/comments", {
            commentBody: newComment,
            Postid: id,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            const commentToAdd = { commentBody: newComment };
            setComments([...comments, commentToAdd]);
            setNewComment("");
        });
    };

    console.log(postObject);

    return (
        <div className="post-section-wrapper">
            {/* <div>
                <div className="title">
                    {postObject.title}
                </div>
                <div className="image">
                    <img src={postObject.image}></img>
                </div>
                <div className="message">
                    {postObject.postText}
                </div>
            </div> */}
            <div className="comments-wrapper">
                <div className="">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Comment..."
                        autoComplete="off"
                        value={newComment}
                        onChange={(event) => {
                        setNewComment(event.target.value);
                        }}
                    />
                    <button onClick={addComment}> Add Comment</button>
                </div>
                <div className="comments-row">
                    {comments.map((comment) => 
                        (
                            <div key={comment.id} className="comment">
                                {comment.commentBody}
                            </div>
                        )
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Post;
```

Thank you very very much!!!

Comment: Can you post some code and a brief description of how your content is laid out?

Comment: I am so sorry, I just realised that the links to my screenshots of my code weren't working properly

Comment: Posting the actual code in here rather than screenshots would be vastly beneficial so that people can analyze the code here. Click the {} in the editor, or the <> if you want to add a snippet. :)

Comment: Ok I'll do that

Comment: @JoelHager could you please help me go from -3 to -2 so my post gets a better view?

Comment: Other than the specified paths for the routes not looking correct I don't really see an issue with the way you are sending the `id` in the navigation PUSH. Perhaps a *running* codesandbox that accurately reproduces the issue would be more beneficial. Could you try creating a minimal, complete, and reproducible example in a codesandbox for us to inspect and live debug in?

Answer (score 0):

@DrewReese and @JoelHager Thank you so much for checking my code and for your advice. In the meantime I found out that we can pass to a component, aside from the pathname, other values with history.push that we retrieve by using useLocation in the component that we want to. I will answer my own question and add the code.

Here is my Forum component, I prefer adding the entire code so everything is clear. In forParams you will see how I pass the value that I need with useHistory and the attribute state and detail.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import Post from '../Post/Post';
import './TrainingsWakeupRebirth.scss';
import axios from 'axios';

const TrainingsWakeupRebirth = (props) => {
    
    let history = useHistory();

    // const forumSectionRef = useRef();
    // const postSectionRef = useRef();
    

    const forumSection = document.getElementById('forum-block-wrapper');
    const postSection = document.getElementById('post-section');

    const showPost = () => {
        if (forumSection.style.display === 'block') {
            return forumSection.style.display = 'none',
            postSection.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            return forumSection.style.display = 'block',
            postSection.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    const [listOfPosts, setListsOfPosts] = useState([]);
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);

    const postsPerPage = 2;
    const pagesVisited = pageNumber * postsPerPage;


    const displayPosts = listOfPosts.slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + postsPerPage).map((value, key) => {

        const forParams = () => {
            history.push(
                {
                    pathname: `#forum#${value.id}`,
                    state: { detail: value.id }
                }
            );
        }

        const executeAll = () => {
            forParams();
            showPost();
        }

        return (
            <div key={key} onClick={() => {executeAll()}}>
                <div className="topic-row">
                    <div className="topic-title">{value.title}</div>
                    <div className="topic-image">
                        <img src={value.image} alt=""></img>
                    </div>
                    <div className="topic-message">{value.postText}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });

    const pageCount = Math.ceil(listOfPosts.length / postsPerPage);

    const changePage = ({selected}) => {
        setPageNumber(selected); 
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/posts").then((response) => {
            setListsOfPosts(response.data);
        });
    }, []);

    console.log(listOfPosts);

    return (
        <div className="forum" id="forum">
            <div className="forum-section-wrapper page" id="forum-wrapper">
                <div className="fluid-grid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <div className="title">
                                <h1><span className="first-title-part">Krishna</span><span className="second-title-part">Hara</span></h1>
                            </div>
                            <div className="quote">
                                <span className="quote-left">FORUM</span><span className="quote-right">Eco Village</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <div className="forum-block-wrapper" id="forum-block-wrapper">
                                {displayPosts}
                                <ReactPaginate 
                                    previousLabel={"Previous"}
                                    nextLabel={"Next"}
                                    pageCount={pageCount}
                                    onPageChange={changePage}
                                    containerClassName={"paginationBttns"}
                                    previousLinkClassName={"previousBttn"}
                                    nextLinkClassName={"nextBttn"}
                                    activeClassName={"paginationActive"}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="post-section" id="post-section">
                <div className="fluid-grid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <Post />
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}; 

export default TrainingsWakeupRebirth;
```

In the Post component with useLocation and useEffect I get location.state.detail which is the id of the Post, that with useState I set to the constant postId.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams, useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import './Post.scss';

const Post = (props) => {

    // let { id } = useParams();

    const location = useLocation();

    const [postId, setPostId] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(location.pathname); // result: '#id'
        if(location.state) {
            console.log(location.state.detail); // result: postId
            setPostId(location.state.detail);
        }    
    }, [location]);

    
    const [postObject, setPostObject] = useState({});
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
    const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState("");
    // console.log(id);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/posts/byId/${postId}`).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            setPostObject(response.data);
        });

        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/comments/${postId}`).then((response) => {
            setComments(response.data);
        });
    }, [postId]);

    const addComment = () => {
        axios.post("http://localhost:3001/comments", {
            commentBody: newComment,
            Postid: postId,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            const commentToAdd = { commentBody: newComment };
            setComments([...comments, commentToAdd]);
            setNewComment("");
        });
    };

    if(postObject !== null) {
        console.log(postObject);
    }

    return (
        <div className="post-section-wrapper">
            {postObject !== null 
            ?
            <div className="posts-wrapper">
                <div className="title">
                    {postObject.title}
                </div>
                <div className="image">
                    <img src={postObject.image}></img>
                </div>
                <div className="message">
                    {postObject.postText}
                </div>
            </div>
            :
            null
            }
            <div className="comments-wrapper">
                <div className="">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Comment..."
                        autoComplete="off"
                        value={newComment}
                        onChange={(event) => {
                        setNewComment(event.target.value);
                        }}
                    />
                    <button onClick={addComment}> Add Comment</button>
                </div>
                <div className="comments-row">
                    {comments.map((comment) => 
                        (
                            <div key={comment.id} className="comment">
                                {comment.commentBody}
                            </div>
                        )
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Post;
```